# How to start rhythmbox without plugins?

Tags: rhythmbox

My rhythmbox does not start. I suspect a problem with a plugin. Therefore I would like to start rhythmbox without plugins. How?

Answer (score 0):

From the help page obtained by running `rhythmbox --help`:

```
--disable-plugins                 Disable loading of plugins
```

Therefore, open the terminal using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> and then run:

```
rhythmbox --disable-plugins
```